# Using process env inside mongoose Schema file Nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I need to change the default value of one property in Mongoose Schema based on one environment variable, but when I try to access `process.env.NAME` I get undefined instead of the value inside my `.env` file. I have this in my schema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type PetDocument = Pet & Document;

@Schema()
export class Pet {
  @Prop({ default: process.env.NAME })
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  breed: string;
}

export const PetSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Pet);
```

And this is my Pet Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { PetsService } from './pets.service';
import { Pet, PetSchema } from './schema/pets.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Pet.name,
        useFactory: () => PetSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [PetsService],
})
export class PetsModule {}
```

and this is my App Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PetsModule } from './pets/pets.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        uri: process.env.DB_URI,
      }),
    }),
    PetsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I get the value instead of undefined inside my Schema file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need include dotenv package to read the .env file at the top of the Schema file. First install the dotenv package if you haven't done this yet: `npm i dotenv`

```js
require('dotenv').config();
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type PetDocument = Pet & Document;

@Schema()
export class Pet {
  @Prop({ default: process.env.NAME }) // shouldn't be undefined anymore

.......
```

Comment: There is no way to do it with the ConfigService from nestjs or something like that? I could not find but wanted to be sure

Comment: Yes, this could be achieved with the config module, you should set the isGlobal to true, to have your config globally avaliable. (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)

Comment: Its set to true already as you can see in my app module. Not working as expected though :/

Comment: is the .env in the root of your nestjs application?

Comment: Yes, it is in the root of the app

Comment: @Otávio ConfigService is useless when you try to access env variables in your schema, use dotenv instead